# Missing generated folders in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-annotations

I'm using Android Annotations in my project and I followed the instructions in this blog post http://www.jayway.com/2014/02/21/androidannotations-setup-in-android-studio/

Everything worked fine.

Today I updated Android Studio to latest version (build of 5th june). This requires an update of gradle build tools from 19.0.3 to 19.1.0. And i configured this in my build.gradle.
Annotaion processing still works. The generated files are located in build/source/apt. But this folder isn't visible any more in project explorer. And starting the build complains about the configuration.
But the project seems to run correctly.

This behavior is very annoying. Do I have to change anything in Android Studio? Has anyone a solution or is this just a bug in Android Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author of android-apt has already updated his plugin to support Gradle's new version, just change this line in your build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2+'
```

To

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.3'
```

Comment: I've updated my android-apt plugin to 1.3 as directed but I'm still getting AS saying that it can't find my AndroidAnnotations generated classes. Are there any other changes needed for this latest upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

The Android Studio Team changed the behavior of the IDE "for better IDE integration". Therefore the output directory of the apt-plugin v 1.2 will not be recognized as generated sources folder any more.

the plugin author knows about it and will provide a fix
https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/issue/13/compatibility-with-011-android-plugin